# How to use SelectToken with square brackets?

Tags: vb.net, json.net, linq-to-json

How can I get the value or make a SelectToken, if the Name of the JToken includes square brackets? `tmpJToken.Value(Of String)("3/32[v]")` or `tmpJToken.SelectToken("3/32[v]")`

Do I have to escape the square brackets?

The JSON looks like:

```
["BeginOfEnumerable",
  [
    {
        "Classification": [
            "/",
            "/Document/"
            
        ],
        "FieldValues": {
            "/0": "8854723",                
            "/3/32[v]": "1856929"                
        },
        "Key": "urn:key:Document:1856929"
    }
],
"EndOfEnumerable"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [SelectToken with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm).

```
Dim result = tmpJToken.SelectToken("$..FieldValues.['/3/32[v]']")
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WvHAwr)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for the case `["FieldValues", {"3/32[v]": "1856929"}]`
Is the syntax different for VB.Net?

Comment: Please excuse the confusion about the simplified JSON. Now I have pasted the complete, original JSON above.

Comment: @Mec-Eng I have updated the answer based on the original JSON